# How to use nested select queries in Drupal 7

Tags: database

How can I write the following query in a Drupal-friendly way?

```
select max(cnt) from 
(select COUNT(*) as cnt from Det a,
dbo.Mem b where a.no=b.no
group by b.no) X
go
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're going cross-database I think using `db_select()` could get quite complicated. I might be wrong though, it might just work.

Either way, you could always just run the query directly with `db_query()`:

```
$sql = '
  select max(cnt) from 
  (select COUNT(*) as cnt from Det a,
  dbo.Mem b where a.no=b.no
  group by b.no)';

$count = db_query($sql)->fetchField();
```

Comment: I agree with this one. Furthermore, be sure that you don't use {} brackets around tables names in the "foreign" database as Drupal will attempt to add table prefixes.

Comment: @sbrattla Very good point, didn't think of that